# django social auth integrate "register with email"

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-socialauth

I am using django social auth in my project and wanted to add email registration on my website as well. I can think of hacking it in since I have played with DSA quite a bit now, but this seemed like a pretty standard problem people using DSA would run into. Is there a elegant way to do this integration?

**UPDATE**:
One of the major reason I am asking is, I dont want to use another django plugin only to find out later that it doesnt play well with DSA. Would appreciate if someone who has got this to work could share.

Comment: IMHO you can look at django-allauth which is as simple and powerful as django-social-auth and has integrated email registration. So all auth code can be done with one django app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will wait for A. Rista to confirm if django-registration works fine. otherwise will shift to django-allauth. Its not an urgent requirement but something I want to know if and when I decide to enable email registrations.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using social_auth successfully with [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) in one project. Registration with Facebook/Google works well, also email registration works as expected.

Django-registration had some issues with Django 1.5, but I believe they are fixed. I'm just updating this project from Django 1.4 to 1.5 so hopefully I can confirm this in a week or so.

Comment: Thanks, waiting for you to confirm :)

Comment: Hi nik-v, I can confirm that django-registration works well with django 1.5, although I have never used it with django-social-auth yet.